# "less than(<)" doesn't work like it's supposed to

Tags: c#, windows

I'm making a piece of code that takes the fibonacci sequence below 4 000 000 and sums up the even numbers. in order to do this I made an easy piece of code that should work but the "C" variable goes over the 4 000 000 where it shouldn't (it ends on the number:"5 702 887"), as you can see here:

```
int amount = 4000000;
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int C = 0;
int answer = 0;

while (C < amount)
{
    C = A + B;

    if (C % 2 == 0)
    {
       answer = answer + C;
    }

    A = B;
    B = C;
}
```

Comment: I'd be worried if C didn't end up equal or over 4000000.  That's the exact condition that ends the loop.

Comment: The title of your question is indicating that your fundamental problem is actually your attitude, not your misunderstanding.  Which is more likely: that `<` is broken, or that you, a beginner, have a false belief?  The question should be "what mistake have I made?" not "less-than is broken". Stop thinking that code *should* work any way other than it does; if you believe that simple code should be doing something different, odds are very good that your belief, not the code, is the thing that is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

You're modifying `C` *after* you check its value. The operator is working as expected.

Your `while` condition is being evaluated when `C = 3524578`, then you're incrementing it to the >5,000,000 number, using it, and checking again.

Remember that `while` loops will always exit when the condition is `false`.

You should probably adjust the order of your tests. For instance,

```
int amount = 4000000;
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int C = 3; // I've changed this to give an appropriate start value
int answer = 0;

while (C < amount)
{
    if (C % 2 == 0)
    {
       answer = answer + C;
    }

    A = B;
    B = C;

    C = A + B; // I've moved this so that answer is not in between the altering of this value and the check for it.
}
```

You could also implement a `for` loop, which will perform this action in a bit more language-native way.

```
int amount = 4000000;
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int answer = 0;

for (int C = 3; C < amount; C = A + B)
{
    if (C % 2 == 0)
    {
       answer = answer + C;
    }

    A = B;
    B = C;
}
```

The difference here is that the predicate expression is evaluated every time `C` is set.

---

I'm in an analogy mood, and I don't think I really explained the actual bug here as much as I just gave the proper code to resolve the issue (teach a man to fish, as they say), so here's a real world example of a flaw in logic like this.

Let's say you're eating orange slices and you absolutely hate seeds and want nothing to do with any oranges that contain them. Regularly, you'd pick one up, check it for seeds, and eat it if it's clear. If you come across one with seeds in it, then gross, and throw away all your remaining orange slices. In pseudo-code, `while (the next one doesn't have any seeds) { eat it and grab another. }`. Simple enough, right?

However, the way you've written your `while` loop here, you'd be eating a slice, finding seeds in your mouth, then throwing them away. And as you can see, these are very different situations.

This latter one houses folds of regret because you checked the slice (the variable) after eating (using) it, rather than before. You know not to eat any more, sure, but you've already eaten a seed. You would have been much better off to check it before you ate it, since then you'd have known it was contaminated before it came anywhere near your mouth.

Comment: i really appreciate you helping me and explaining it perfectly. but i am afraid that it still gives the same problem. C still ends at 5702887 as you can see here: [link](http://puu.sh/aoHtD/91a93e5e90.png)

Comment: Yes. `C` is going to be that no matter what, unless you apply some weird and unnecessary logic. If you're looking for a quick and dirty solution, the value of `B` will be whatever you had hoped `C` to be.

Comment: I don't know whether my analogy helped even at all, but to stick with that, regardless of which approach you take, you're still going to have to look at the last orange slice to see whether it has seeds. You can't just know ahead of time. The last slice you look at is always the case you hope for it not to be. Thus, `C` is incremented to be above 4,000,000, then it's checked for value, then it's thrown out. It still maintains that high value, though.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that you have a false belief common to beginners. The `while` statement does not terminate the loop *immediately* the moment that the condition is violated.

The correct way to think about a `while` loop is that

```
while(condition) 
    statement
```

is logically the same thing as:

```
continue_label: 
if (!condition) goto break_label;
statement
goto continue_label;
break_label:
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition of a `while` loop is executed only while entering the loop each time. If you look at your code, `C` is assigned after this check. Try printing `C` just before your `C = ...` assignment - you will see that it does not go beyond the limit.

The next assignment exceeds the value, but the while loop is not entered again.

Answer (score 0):

When C is checked its still bellow 4000000 but then inside the iteration it gets raised above the limit(C = A + B) and in the next iteration its above that value and the loop exits.Instead try this "very dirty" implementation:

```
int amount = 4000000;
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int C = 0;
int answer = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < amount; i = A + B)
{
     C = A + B;

     if (C % 2 == 0)
     {
         answer = answer + C;
     }

     A = B;
     B = C;
}
```